# How does the sorcerer's Undead Bloodline Arcana work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, sorcerer, undead

The Bloodline Arcana for the [Undead sorcerer bloodline](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/undead-bloodline/) reads as follows:

> Some undead are susceptible to your mind-affecting spells. Corporeal undead that were once humanoids are treated as humanoids for the purposes of determining which spells affect them.

[Undead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/) have many traits, among them are:

> - Immunity to all mind-affecting effects (charms, compulsions, morale effects, patterns, and phantasms)
> - Immunity to death effects, disease, paralysis, poison, sleep effects, and stunning

The [Color Spray](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/color-spray/) spell is a mind-affecting spell that stuns (and sometimes inflicts other effects). Can a sorcerer with the Undead bloodline stun corporeal once-humanoid undead with Color Spray?

**Interpretation 1:** The undead are treated as humanoid for all purposes related to the spell. Thus they do not have the standard undead immunity to mind-affecting spells or to being stunned.

**Interpretation 2:** The arcana only allows the sorcerer to target undead with spells that *specifically* affect *only* humanoids, such as [Enlarge Person](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/) or [Hold Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hold-person/) (though undead would *still* be immune to Hold Person since it's mind-affecting).

**Interpretation 3:** The arcana only allows the sorcerer to use mind-affecting spells *that target humanoids* on undead. Are there any spells in this category *besides* Hold Person, Charm Person, and Dominate Person? If not, why wouldn't the text just list those spells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### This GM would have the [humanoid](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Humanoid) type effectively *replace* the corporeal creature's [undead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Undead) type with regard to that [undead bloodline](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/undead-bloodline/) sorcerer's mind-affecting spells

Although it's *possible* to read the two sentences of the sorcerer's [undead bloodline](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/undead-bloodline/) **bloodline arcana** in isolation, I disagree that a reader *should*. When the description says, "Some undead are susceptible to your mind-affecting spells," the reader also needs to know *which* undead and *in what way* such undead are susceptible, and those're covered by the second sentence. To clarify with brackets, that second sentence should probably be as follows: "Corporeal undead that were once humanoids are treated as humanoids for the purposes of determining which [of your mind-affecting] spells affect them."

Thus this GM would rule that when that undead bloodline sorcerer casts a spell that does *not* possess the [descriptor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Descriptor-) mind-affecting, that spell is wholly unaffected by the bloodline arcana. For example, although each spell normally targets humanoids, because the spells are *not* also mind-affecting, the bloodline arcana would *not* allow a sorcerer to make bigger with an [*enlarge person*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/) spell a once-humanoid [zombie](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/zombie/zombie-kobold/), paralyze ironically with the spell [*ghoul's touch*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/ghoul-touch/) a once-humanoid [ghoul](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/ghoul/), or shrivel with the spell [*wither limb*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wither-limb/) a [wight](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/wight/)'s leg. In short, it seems to this GM that if the sorcerer's spell is *not* mind-affecting, then the spell's effect is unchanged.

However, when that undead bloodline sorcerer casts a spell that possesses the descriptor mind-affecting, this GM would treat any once-humanoid corporeal creature that possesses the type [undead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Undead) as possessing, instead, the type [humanoid](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Humanoid) for the all the spell's purposes, and that humanoid type would determine all the spell's effect. Thus, at its most basic, in this GM's campaigns, such a sorcerer could befriend with a [*charm person*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-person/) spell a once-humanoid [ghast](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/ghoul/ghoul-ghast/), send off to slumberland with the spell [*sleep*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sleep/) a group of once-humanoid [skeletons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/skeleton-medium/), and exercise mental control using the spell [*dominate person*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dominate-person/) over a once-human and extraordinarily unlucky [lich](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/lich/).

Further, because this GM would have the creature's [undead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Undead) type effectively yet completely *replaced* by the [humanoid](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Humanoid) type with regard to the sorcerer's mind-affecting spells, the once-humanoid undead creature would likewise lose any of its immunities and resistances due to its type against that sorcerer's mind-affecting spells. For example, a once-humanoid [mummy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/mummy/) could be stunned by the sorcerer's [*color spray*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/color-spray/) spell, despite undead creatures normally being immune to the condition [stunned](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Stunned), and a once-humanoid [vampire](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/vampire/) would be dealt Strength ability damage and be stunned after succeeding on the saving throw against the sorcerer's [*weird*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/weird/) spell, despite normally being immune to *all three of* effects that require a Fortitude saving throw unless the effect also affects objects *and* damage to its physical ability scores *and* the condition stunned.

This *can* lead to some unusual situations, like a once-human corporeal undead creature believing it's been poisoned after failing its saving throw against the spell [*illusory poison*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/illusory-poison/) even though it's normally immune to poison, or a once-human corporeal undead creature believing it's suffocating after failing its saving throw against the spell [*phantasmal asphyxiation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/phantasmal-asphyxiation/) even though it doesn't breathe. This GM, though, sees such unusual (and not to mention *amusing*) effects as features rather than bugs and suspects that any sorcerer that'd pick the [undead bloodline](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/undead-bloodline/) would also. In fact, I suspect such a sorcerer would pick to know such spells *deliberately* so that he *could* revel in his undead brethren's strange, normally-impossible discomfort!

Answer (score 1):

Undead would be acceptable targets of Hold Person, as well as Charm Person, Dominate Person, etc.

> Some undead **are susceptible to your mind-affecting spells**. Corporeal undead that were once humanoids are treated as humanoids for the purposes of determining **which spells affect them.**

Emphasis added.

They are also *targettable* by Color Spray... but it will be ineffective. They are still immune to the Stunned *condition*. You only bypass the racial feature(s) indicated in your ability.